# TouchJSON not working to retrieve data on iPhone

Tags: php, objective-c, json, implementation, touchjson

I am trying to use TouchJSON to retrieve data from a php page with json output. I have followed the same steps as an example project I downloaded from and it still isn't working. When I select the section containing the data from my main menu the app crashes. I am including my view controller implementation file. Thanks, enbr.
http://pastie.org/pastes/1070273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem.

Comment: If possible, you should post your solution for others who find your question and have the same problem.